# Passing arguments from Java to url-expression in Spring Integration outbound-gateway

Tags: spring, spring-integration

**RequestGateway.Java**

```
public interface RequestGateway {
    String echo(Map<String, String> request);
    String echo(String request);
}
```

**Test.java**

```
Map<String, String> requestMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
requestMap.put("acccountId", "1111222233334444");
requestMap.put("currencyCode", "USD");
requestMap.put("paymentAmount", "100.00");
RequestGateway paymentRequestGateway = context.getBean("paymentRequestGateway", RequestGateway.class);
String availableCreditBalance = paymentRequestGateway.echo(requestMap);
```

**SIConfig.xml**

```
<int:gateway id="paymentRequestGateway"
                 service-interface="com.api.orchestration.api.RequestGateway"
                 default-request-channel="PaymentAuthRequestChannel"
                 default-reply-channel="ResponseChannel">
        <int:default-header name="Accept" value="application/json; v=3"/>
        <int:default-header name="Content-Type" value="application/json"/>
        <int:default-header name="accountId" expression="payload.get('acccountId')"/>
</int:gateway>

<int-http:outbound-gateway
        id="IG2 Outbound Gateway"
        request-channel="IG2RequestChannel"
        reply-channel="ResponseChannel"
        header-mapper="headerMapper"
        url-expression="'http://localhost:9090/balance/account/'+ headers['accountId']"
        http-method="GET"
        expected-response-type="java.lang.String">
</int-http:outbound-gateway>
```

How do I pass arguments to url-expression from Java Code, I am probably doing something wrong with expression in default-header?

This works with url-expression in http:outbound-gateway

```
< int:default-header name="accountId" value="1111222233334444"/>
```

This does not..

```
< int:default-header name="accountId" expression="payload.get('acccountId')"/>
```

**"Error: EL1007E:(pos 0): Property or field 'payload' cannot be found on null"**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use

```
< int:default-header name="accountId" expression="payload.get('acccountId')"/>
```

when creating the message; the message (and hence the payload) doesn't exist yet.

You should be able to use `#args[0]['accountId']`.

There is no `#root` object for the evaluation. See **Expressions and "Global" Headers** [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#gateway-configuration-annotations).